# How do I address the following security items with Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage, zap

Does anybody have a clue how to address the following security issues that come with scanning Azure blob storage through ZAP:

1. Remote OS Command Injection: 
   `https://<xxx>.blob.core.windows.net/00d36000000tnwaeaa/06836000000kUsRAAU?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=<yyy>%3D&se=2016-10-07T07%3A25%3A13Z&sp=rw%3Bstart-sleep+-s+5`.

   Azure requires the 'sp' parameter, however this could be hijacked with insertion of OS commands as shown above. Is there a way to address this in Azure.
   I haven't found any.
2. What is the way to set up following with Azure blob server - 
   X-Frame-Options Header Not Set, Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set, Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled

Please help me as my Azure web service is failing the above ZAP scans.

Comment: As I know, SAS url only support permission: Read (r),Write (w),Delete (d),List (l),Add (a),Create (c),Update (u),Process (p). See more at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt584140.aspx). I don't think the other parameter will work.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, it is not possible to modify the parameters for components of the SAS, as they are used to generate the signature (sig= param), and then validated in the service.  If they do not match the values used to generate the original signature, the request is rejected.

For #2, Azure storage does not allow modifying the headers returned, but it does allow configuring CORS.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx